# Ionic override behavior on back gesture

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, gesture, ionic5

I want to overwrite the behaviour of the back gesture (Swiping from the left of the screen, pressing back, etc). Instead of just navigating to the previous page in the stack, depending on where you are in the app - I would like to present the user with options - the most important one being:

> If you are on the home screen, a [toast message](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast) should display saying `Press again to exit`, and then exit the application.

I don't want the user to route back to the login screen accidentally, which is what's currently happening. I know I can use guards to check if you are logged in - and if you are, just route to the home page when you hit the login page. Is this the best way to do this though?